# trying to change a ajax button to a php (html) link

Tags: php, html, ajax, hyperlink

thanks for reading my question.

i am working whith this peice of code and it works great but i am trying to customise the button into a link

origanl code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>An XHTML 1.0 Strict standard template</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxFunction(id, url){
        var xmlHttp;
        try {// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();     
        } catch (e) {// Internet Explorer
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                //Get the response from the server and extract the section that comes in the body section of the second html page avoid inserting the header part of the second page in your first page's element
                var respText = xmlHttp.responseText.split('<body>');
                elem.innerHTML = respText[1].split('</body>')[0];
            }
        }

        var elem = document.getElementById(id);
        if (!elem) {
            alert('The element with the passed ID doesn\'t exists in your page');
            return;
        }

        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }       
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Make Ajax Call" id="ajax" onclick="ajaxFunction('test','one.htm');"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

i am trying to convert the

```
<input type="button" value="Make Ajax Call" id="ajax" onclick="ajaxFunction('test','one.htm');"/>
```

part into a link instead of a button to do the same job.

how would i do this?

i have tried the following

```
<a href="test3.php"  value="Make Ajax Call" id="ajax" onclick="ajaxFunction('test','one.htm');">xxx</a>
```

also i am wanting the content in the div to change

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

what i mean is if the content was "example" after i click the link it would change to the other content

with the replie below it dont give me a "cant find error" it just dont show me the content in the file

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your anchor link is going to test3.php preventing the javascript from ever running.

You can do two things:

Change `href='test3.php'` to `href='#'`

Or change `onclick="ajaxFunction('test','one.htm');"` to `onclick="ajaxFunction('test','one.htm'); return false;"`

--

Also move

```
var elem = document.getElementById(id);
```

Above the `onreadystate` function, the problem there is elem is undefined when trying to set innerHTML for your div.

--

So first swap the setting of var elem above xmlHttp.onreadystatechange:

```
var elem = document.getElementById(id);
if (!elem) {
    alert('The element with the passed ID doesn\'t exists in your page');
    return;
}

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        //Get the response from the server and extract the section that comes in the body section of the second html page avoid inserting the header part of the second page in your first page's element
        var respText = xmlHttp.responseText.split('<body>');
        elem.innerHTML = respText[1].split('</body>')[0];
    }
}
```

This makes it so elem is accessible inside of the function block of the onreadystatechange with the element of the container you want to change with the return value from your ajax call (The 'test' div)

Then you can remove the `<form>` and `<input type='button ... />` and replace it with:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ajaxFunction('test','one.htm'); return false;">Make Ajax Call</a>
```

Comment: thats great :) any idea on the second part of my question regarding content in the div as default?

Comment: please update my question with the correct code i still cant get this to work :( lol

Comment: See answer revision, hope that helps you a bit more, if you still are not getting it to work, there may be something else going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the default click even of an `a` you must remember cancel the default with `event.preventDefault();`

I don't know if you can do it with inline notation but you can use `return false;` as well:

```
onclick="ajaxFunction('test','one.htm'); return false;"
```

`return false;` will do `event.preventDefault()` and `event.cancelBubble()`, but it has some problems: for instance when an error occurs your event wont be cancelled. I recommend using the EventListener API and `preventDefault()` but I feel like it's outside the scope of this question.